# Insert a duplicate key value into binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write an insert method for my binary search tree class. I want it to be able to insert a new value into a tree that already has an existing node with this same data value must cause a new node to be created in the right subtree of the existing node. Here's my code. I'm getting an unhandled exception error while trying to compile. I don't know what I did wrong there. If someone can explain the reason why the compiler is giving me error, it would be great. Thanks :)

```
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::insert
                 (const elemType& insertItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
    nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
    nodeType<elemType> *newNode;  //pointer to create the node

    newNode = new nodeType<elemType>;
    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->lLink = NULL;
    newNode->rLink = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        current = root;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;

            if (current->info == insertItem)
            {
                current = current->rLink;
                trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
                if (newNode->info <= current->info) //this is where the compiler say the error is
                    newNode->rLink = current;
                else
                    newNode->lLink = current;
            }
            else if (current->info > insertItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }//end while

        if (trailCurrent->info < insertItem)
            trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
        else if (trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
            trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;
    }
}//end insert
```

Comment: Can you post the compile error?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00FB84FA in BinaryTree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: "...must cause a new node to be created in the right subtree of the existing code." I think you meant "existing  node". Regardless, does this mean you want it to *continue* traversal until it finds a valid insertion point (a null pointer) or do you intend it to be hung **directly** to the right of the existing node and the rest of the (potentially already existing) subtree on the right side to be arranged according, hung on the right of the *new* node? There is a difference between the two.

Comment: @WhozCraig I want it to be hung directly to the right of the existing node and then modify the already existing subtree to go on the correct side of the new node

Comment: @NguyenTran ok, but note, there is only one "correct" side that existing subtree can be hung on. Because it was "greater" than the previous node and our new node is a duplicate of that, it can only logically be placed on the *right* of our new node (which goes on the right of the existing node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is what you're trying to do:

```
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::insert(const elemType& insertItem)
{
    nodeType<elemType> **pp = &root;
    while (*pp)
    {
        if (insertItem < (*pp)->info)
            pp = &(*pp)->lLink;
        else if ((*pp)->info < insertItem)
            pp = &(*pp)->rLink);
        else break;
    }

    // note: this is cleaner if the the nodeType constructor
    //  is parameterized. (hint hint)
    nodeType<elemType> *p = new nodType<elemType>;
    p->info = insertItem;
    p->lLink = NULL;

    if (*pp)
    {
        p->rLink = (*pp)->rLink;
        (*pp)->rLink = p;
    }
    else
        *pp = p;
}
```

**How it works**

The basics of finding an insertion point for a new non-existing key are mundane, so I'll not cover them. The case of locating an existing key is, however, interesting. We use a pointer-to-pointer to hold the address of each node pointer we encounter while walking down the tree. When we have a match the loop will exit and `*pp` will **not** be null. When that happens, our new node has it's right-pointer set to the matched right-pointer, and the matched node's right-pointer becomes the new node. The remainder of the tree remains as-is.

I.e. adding a second 7 in this:

```
        5
   3        7
2     4  6     8
```

results in

```
        5
   3        7
2     4  6     7
                 8
```

then adding another 3 results in:

```
         5
   3           7
2     3     6     7
        4           8
```

All of this, of course, assuming i understood the problem.No attempt at rotations or balancing is done. That I leave to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Comment: @NguyenTran I suspected as much. Spend some time learning about, and practicing, *tons* of double-indirection code. There are many problems, particularly dynamic chained node problems (linked lists, trees, etc) where it *greatly* simplifies the algorithms by addressing the pointers *in the data structure*, not just their values. This is one such example.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a deal with yourself. This deal can be like this:

The left subtree will have values *less or equal* than the one in the root and so on.

In code you have:

```
if (trailCurrent->info < insertItem)
  trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
```

which after the deal would be like this:

```
if (trailCurrent->info <= insertItem)
  trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
```

Comment: I know what you mean. However, I don't want to insert the new node to the end of the tree. I want to insert it right below the node that have the same value and modify the structure of the tree, making the subtree below that node becomes the subtree of the new node

Comment: Apply the same logic as mentioned, but in your inner nodes @NguyenTran. When you find were you want to put your new value, put a pointer to the left subtree (and one in the right one), so that you do not lose them. Insert the new value and make the the two subtrees the children of the new inserted node. I suggest you read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Insertion

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct but

```
trialCurrent = current;
```

trialCurrent is equal to current

```
if(current->info == insertItem)
    current = current->rLink;
    trialCurrent->rlink = newnode;
```

current is equal to current->rLink, then wouldn't trialCurrent->rLink be equal to current?

Comment: This actually gets me pretty close. But I lost access to all the subtree after I create the node :D I will try to figure out the problem. Thanks